# Why is React/TypeScript/axios ignoring my CSRF cookies?

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, cookies, csrf

Good day, fine Stack Overflow citizens. I have a Django back end serving a React front end. React uses axios to perform requests and handle CSRF magic (which Django employs out of the box).

I had a fun time reacquainting myself with the ins and outs of CSRF and CORS, and finally managed to get things running with Django (using Django REST Framework) serving on `http://localhost:8000` and React on `http://localhost:3000`. I especially love how you can set the following and dust your hands off from otherwise tiring details:

```
axios.defaults.xsrfCookieName = XSRF_COOKIE_NAME;
axios.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = XSRF_HEADER_NAME;
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

However, now that I've deployed this code into my production environment, Django complains when I try to log in (with the message *CSRF verification failed. Request aborted*).

After some digging, I found this to be because even though Django sends `Set-Cookie` headers with the CSRF token, it **isn't being set in my browser**. I have the following headers in my client request:

```
Host: backend.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://frontend.example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://frontend.example.com/login
```

And this is the server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: gunicorn/20.0.4
Date: Wed, 13 May 2020 09:44:33 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Wed, 13 May 2020 09:44:33 GMT
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
Vary: Cookie, Origin
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Content-Length: 2752
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://frontend.example.com
Set-Cookie: csrftoken=5EStJqz3pq332JlHhlWGGoHkv5pHgVSrYtEQM5wBEcXRYHDErYtf82mvw30kCDw1; expires=Wed, 12 May 2021 09:44:33 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; Secure
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

Compared to the above request, the same on `localhost` sends the `X-CSRFToken` header with every request after picking it up from the configured `csrftoken` cookie set on previous requests. Production, however, doesn't. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

Anyone to the rescue?

### Update 1 (May 14)

I forgot to mention that my production machines are on Heroku. I have two; one for CI and one for "proper prod". The former is the one with issues, but the latter has started working for me after deploying the front end to `myapp.com` and the back end to `api.myapp.com`, both securely. It worked by setting :

- `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` to `('https://myapp.com',)`
- `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` to `myapp.com`
- `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `myapp.com`
- `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` to `myapp.com`

I'm still not sure why my CI environment doesn't work. I suspect it might have something to do with being under the `herokuapp.com` domain, while "proper prod" has a dedicated domain.

Answer (score 0):

> `herokuapp.com` is included in the Mozilla Foundation’s Public Suffix List. This list is used in recent versions of several browsers, such as Firefox, Chrome and Opera, to limit how broadly a cookie may be scoped. In other words, in browsers that support the functionality, applications in the `herokuapp.com` domain are prevented from setting cookies for `*.herokuapp.com`.
>
> This has no effect on applications using custom domains.

From the [Heroku Dev Center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com). I have to say I find it a crime that there's no way to tell that this is happening in the top browsers of right now. Silent failure is the only option, with no way to get all those lost hours of sleep back. Oh well!